# else block within ng-if

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to render different buttons based on if a property is starred or not. The logic for checking if a property is starred is working fine. This is my code.

```
<li class="list-inline-item" *ngIf="property.starred === true; else elseBlock">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sendLike(property.id)"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
    <ng-template #elseBlock><button>Test</button></ng-template>
</li>
```

The true condition is working fine. But if the property.starred is false, then the elseblock never renders.

Any ideas here

Comment: The else block can't possible be rendered, since it's inside of the `li` that isn't rendered. Put the ngIf on the button, not on the li. It's the button that you want to hide if the property is not starred. Not the li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">
  <button *ngIf="property.starred; else elseBlock" 
          class="btn btn-primary" 
          (click)="sendLike(property.id)">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
  </button>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <button>Test</button>
  </ng-template>
</li>
```